# Not able to delete an object from immer,redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, immer.js

I am using Redux Toolkit, having a slice where i am doing crud operations in a slice.list

but I am not able to filter slice.list

here is my code...

```js
    showsRemoved: (shows, action) => {
      shows.list.filter((show) => show.id !== action.payload.deletedShowId);
    },
```

the show is succesfully deleted from the server, but I also want to do update my redux store, so I am filtering the shows with an id which is coming from the server. but code flow is not working.
I have added these console.logs to check the data i am manipulating. here's the code

```js
    showsRemoved: (shows, action) => {
      shows.list.filter((show) => {
        console.log(show.id, action.payload.deletedShowId);
        console.log(show.id !== action.payload.deletedShowId);
        return show.id !== action.payload.deletedShowId;
      });
    },
```

and its output in console looks fine, here the ss

[image]

what am i doing wrong? explain, solution, best practice?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the new state from your reducer after [filtering out the deleted show](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/update-patterns#nested-data-structures).

```
showsRemoved: (shows, action) => {
  shows.list = shows.list.filter((show) => show.id !== action.payload.deletedShowId);
  return shows;
},
```

Comment: same problem getting in updating... can you help here is the question I just ask 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73850430/not-able-to-update-an-object-in-immer-redux-toolkit-store